# ActionBarCompat: Set Navigation Mode

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using ActionBarCompat in my project.
The problem I have now is that I need a spinner to show in the actionbar. A standard ActionBar can use `.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)` but this is unavailable in the action bar compat code.

Is there a way around this? What are other options (besides a layout redesign.)

Comment: Strongly consider moving to a real compatibility library ([ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)). It's a full backport of the real native action bar and does everything the real action bar does. ActionBarCompat is a joke.

Comment: I completely agree. In the same amount of time I spent setting up ActionbarCompat, with ActionBarSherlock I had a better looking Action Bar with more supported functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in the code provided by ActionBarCompat.

It provides an ActionBar in it's most basic form for use by all platforms.

A better alternative is useing ActionBarSherlock. The setup very similar and more functionality is available out of the box.
http://actionbarsherlock.com/